# GPU accelerated neural networks

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, gpu, neural-network

I am looking for gratis software that is GPU accelerated that can work with neural networks. I have seen many pieces of software that I can use for neural networks but many of them do not have GPU acceleration. Here are my requirements

Support for the backpropagation algorithm.

I would like support for a genetic algorithm such as NEAT but it is not required

A good nice to use interface

I would like it to work on windows but  I could also use it on Linux

That is it for my requirements. In case you are wondering what GPUs I use I use Nvidia GPUs. So the application would have to support CUDA

Comment: Is coding directly like in Theano ok?

Comment: There is quite a range of choices here. Are you interested in specific uses of neural networks? Interest in NEAT might imply networks for AI, A-life, reinforcement learning, robotics. Whilst machine vision networks are currently monster CNNs that almost *require* GPU acceleration in order to train them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/):

- open source (BSD 2-Clause license)
- gratis
- Easy to compile on Linux/OS X, harder on Windows
- GPU support for Nvidia
- on CPU, makes use of multithreading
- use the backpropagation algorithm
- allows the user to define neural network using config files
- MLP, CNN but no RNN yet
- written in C++ but Python and Matlab binds available

FYI:

- [Script to install Caffe and pycaffe on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31396229/395857).
- [How to train a caffe model?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31659332/395857)

Comment: Note caffe has been merged into pytorch - https://caffe2.ai/blog/2018/05/02/Caffe2_PyTorch_1_0.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Python package [theanets](https://github.com/lmjohns3/theanets):

- open source (MIT License)
- gratis
- it's a wrapper around Theano (the latter can use your GPU if Nvidia, AMD is not fully supported yet).
- on CPU, does not make use of multithreading
- Easy to compile on Linux/OS X, harder on Windows
- MLP, RNN

The following [code](http://theanets.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) shows how easy it is to specify an ANN and train it:

```
import climate
import theanets
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

climate.enable_default_logging()

# Create a classification dataset.
X, y = make_classification(
    n_samples=3000, n_features=100, n_classes=10, n_informative=10)
X = X.astype('f')
y = y.astype('i')
cut = int(len(X) * 0.8)  # training / validation split
train = X[:cut], y[:cut]
valid = X[cut:], y[cut:]

# Build a classifier model with 100 inputs and 10 outputs.
exp = theanets.Experiment(theanets.Classifier, layers=(100, 10))

# Train the model using SGD with momentum.
exp.train(train, valid, algorithm='sgd', learning_rate=1e-4, momentum=0.9)

# Show confusion matrices on the training/validation splits.
for label, (X, y) in (('training:', train), ('validation:', valid)):
    print(label)
    print(confusion_matrix(y, exp.network.predict(X)))
```